# Windows 8.1: Keep remote monitors/displays off during RDP

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop, sleep, power

In the mornings, I leave my user account logged into my Windows 8.1 Pro desktop.  My monitors power off a few minutes before I leave my home.

Later, I RDP to that PC using the same username.. which takes me to the remote desktop console.

However, that wakes up my remote monitors.  Is there anyway for me to tell Windows NOT to turn my remote monitors on (since I'm not even at the remote location)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's on old question, but I had the same problem and found why it is happening. I found out that it's "by design" on this website https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby-wake-sources

> Remote Desktop can turn on the display on the target system.

And during my testing, I found out that during Remote Desktop connection monitor indeed wakes up, but it goes to sleep after X minutes, and those X minutes are that which you configure in Power Options "turn monitor off after X minutes of inactivity" (or something like that, I don't have English Windows).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about making windows do this, but you could try an old technology approach & turn off your monitor.

That would solve your issue.